# Cocol/R predictive parser implementation Java

Tags: java, parsing

I´m working on a predicitive parser for COCOL/R

Here´s the part of the grammar that I´m trying to parse right now:

[image]

The squared bracket mean 1 or none
The curly braces mean 0 or more.

```
public void Cocol( ){
    lookahead = in.next();
    if(lookahead.equals("COMPILER")){
        match("COMPILER");
        match("ident");
        ScannerSpecification();
        match("END");
        match("ident");
        match(".");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("SYNTAX ERROR: \nCOMPILER expected, Found: "+lookahead);
        try {
            ArrayList<Integer> line = findLineOf(lookahead);
            System.out.println("Line: "+line);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ScannerCocol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}

public void ScannerSpecification(){
    // 1 o mas veces “CHARACTERS” { SetDecl }
    if(lookahead.equals("CHARACTERS")){
        match("CHARACTERS");
        // 0 or More SETDecl

    }
    if (lookahead.equals("KEYWORDS")){
        //PENDING....     
    }

    if( WhiteSpaceDecl()){
          //PENDING....
    }
    boolean res=match(".");
    if(res==false){
        System.out.println("SYNTAX ERROR: \n \".\" expected, Found: "+lookahead);

        //Encontrando linea
        try {
            ArrayList<Integer> line = findLineOf(lookahead);
            System.out.println("Line: "+line);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ScannerCocol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }

}
public boolean match(String terminal){
    boolean result;
    if(terminal.equals("number")){
        result = automataNumber.simularAFN(lookahead, automataNumber.inicial, conjuntoSimbolos);
        return result;
    }
    else if(terminal.equals("ident")){
        result = automataident.simularAFN(lookahead,automataident.inicial,conjuntoSimbolos);
        return result;
    }
    else if(terminal.equals("string")){
       result =  automataString.simularAFN(lookahead,automataString.inicial,conjuntoSimbolos);
       return result;
    }   
    else if(terminal.equals("char")){
        result = automataChar.simularAFN(lookahead,automataChar.inicial,conjuntoSimbolos);
        return result;
    } 
    else{
        if(this.lookahead.equals(terminal)){
            lookahead= in.next();
            return true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error: Se esperaba: "+terminal);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem I´m facing is on the cases where I have to search for 0 or more derivations of a production (For instance on the SetDecl ) . I know I have to keep trying to match the productions until I can´t match one, but I don´t know how to discern when I have to report an error from when I just have to continue reading the input.

Can anyone give me some ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple model for a predictive parser is that each function corresponding to a production returns a boolean value (success or failure). Then a rule which includes a "zero or more" expansion can be written, for example:

```
if(lookahead.equals("CHARACTERS")){
    match("CHARACTERS");
    while (SetDecl()) ;
    return true;
}
/* ... */
```

By the way, it's actually handy to define an operator which consumes the lookahead string:

```
if(lookahead.matches("CHARACTERS")){
    while (SetDecl()) ;
    return true;
}
/* ... */
```

Where `lookahead.matches(s)` is basically `if(lookahead.equals(s){match(s); return true;}else{return false;}`

The general rule for any production function is this:

1) If the first object in the rule (token or non-terminal) cannot be matched, leave the input untouched and return false.

2) If any other object in the rule cannot be matched, emit an error and try to recover.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer. I think the rules you gave me are just what I needed. I just want to know if I´m getting this right:

If I have a non terminal between braces, I just have to check the first object and see if it matches, if it doesn´t I continue with the rest of  the input without reporting an error.

What if I find an error on another object that is not the first? and I´m just verifying the while loop? I think it should also continue without reporting or I´m I wrong?

Comment: @PabloEstrada: 100% correct. The while loop always succeeds, since it represents 0 or more iterations and 0 iterations can always match. For "one or more X" you effectively do "X [X]", which translates to "if (!X()) return false; while(X()); return true;"